# Use generic type without argument in protocol extension clause

Tags: swift3, rx-swift

I'd like to extend a protocol with a function if the `associatedtype E` is a `Result<T>`. What I want to achieve is something like the following:

```
extension SharedSequenceConvertibleType where E == Result {

    func filterResult(success: Bool) -> RxCocoa.SharedSequence<Self.SharingStrategy, Self.E> {
        return self.filter { result in
            switch (result) {
            case .Success(_):
                return success
            case .Failure(_):
                return !success
            }
        }
    }
}

enum Result<Element> {
    case Success(Element)
    case Failure(Swift.Error)
}
```

Unfortunately, Swift complains about `Reference to generic type 'Result' requires arguments in <…>`. If I apply the suggested Fix-It to change it to `Result<Any>`, I cannot use `filterResult` on `Result<MyObject>` `'Result<LoginInfo>' is not convertible to 'Result<Any>'`. I don't actually care about the `Element` type here, as you can see.

Is there a way to achieve this in Swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507740/swift-3-extension-constrained-to-a-type?rq=1), I figured that it seems to be neccessary to use a protocol to wrap `Result<Element>` in. The following works:

```
extension SharedSequenceConvertibleType where E: ResultType {

    func filterResult(success: Bool) -> RxCocoa.SharedSequence<Self.SharingStrategy, Self.E> {
        return filter { result in return success == result.isSuccess }
    }
}


protocol ResultType {
    var isSuccess: Bool { get }
}

enum Result<Element>: ResultType {
    var isSuccess: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .Success:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }

    case Success(Element)
    case Failure(Swift.Error)
}
```